# Topological transitivity implies existence of dense forward orbit (understanding proof)

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to understand the following proof(see picture 1). We need to show that there exists a $y\in X$ such that $\overline{O^+(y)}=X$. But in the whole proof there is no $y$ mentioned . Can anyone explain why the forward orbit of $y$ is dense ?

many thanks in advance

[image]

---

The proof uses the following proposition 
[image]

Comment: A value of $y$ **is** mentioned. Namely, $y=x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the sequence $\{n_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of integers (not necessarily positive). Given how the $n_k$ $(k=1,2,\ldots)$ are chosen, we know that $\lim_{k \to \infty} f^{n_k}(x)=x$. Hence $\lim_{k \to \infty} f^l\circ f^{n_k}(x)=f^l(x)$ for any $l \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now for infinitely many positive integers $k$ we must either have that $n_k$ is positive or $n_k$ is negative. If infinitely many $n_k$ are positive then the forward orbit of $x$ is dense in $X$ $\left(\overline{\mathcal{O}^+(x)}=X\right)$. Otherwise, by proposition 2.2.1, the author has shown that $f$ is topologically transitive, and so there is $y \in X$ such that $\overline{\mathcal{O}^+(y)}=X$ (definition of topologically transitive).

Comment: Great I got it know. The only part I dont quite understand is the idea behind showing $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f^{n_k+l}(x)=f^l(x)$

Comment: Well do you understand why $\lim_{k \to \infty} f^{n_k}(x)=x$? 
For the record, this bit is important for understanding why we either have $\mathcal{O}(x) \subseteq \overline{\mathcal{O}^+(x)}$ or  $\mathcal{O}(x) \subseteq \overline{\mathcal{O}^-(x)}$

Comment: $O(x)$ is dense in $X$. Hence $\forall U\subset X$ open: $O(x)\cap U\neq\emptyset$. This means $f^t(x)\in U$ for $\forall t\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence I can find a sequence of positive (or negative integers) $n_k$ with $n_k\rightarrow\infty$ such that $f^{n_k}(x)\in B_{\frac{1}{k}}(x)$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$ (Because we have no isolated points). This is equal to the definition of convergence. So $f^{n_k}(x)\rightarrow x$. Is this the reason why we can say $O(x)\subseteq \overline{O^+(x)}$ ?

Comment: Since $\overline{\mathcal{O}(x)}=X$, for every open set $U \subset X$  there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f^m(x) \in U$. Since $X$ has no isolated points, for $k=1,2,\ldots$ we may find an integer $n_k$ such that $f^{n_k}(x) \in B\left(x, k^{-1}\right)$. So $\lim_{k \to \infty} f^{n_k}(x)=x$. Since $\{n_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is an infinite sequence of integers such that $|n_k| \to \infty$, we must either have that $n_k$ is positive or negative for infinitely many $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Just to be clear, the fact that $X$ has no isolated points is what allows us to have $|n_k| \to \infty$. For example, if $x$ were an isolated point of $X$ then we  could be stuck choosing $n_k=0$  ( $f^0(x)=x$) for infinitely many $k \in \mathbb N$ and so the argument would not follow.

Also, it would be a good idea to be familiar with the two definitions of [everywhere] dense mentioned here: 
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Everywhere_Dense

Comment: I'm getting the big picture, but that $l\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $f^{l+n_k}\rightarrow f^l(x)$ still confusing me.

Comment: We know that $f^l:X \to X$ is a continuous map ( $f$ is a homeomorphism, and the finite composition of continuous maps is a continuous map) and $f^{n_k}(x) \to x$ as $k \to \infty$. So, by the definition of sequential continuity, $\lim_{k \to \infty} f^l\left(\,f^{n_k}\left(x\right)\right) = f^l(x)$ since $f^l$ is continuous at $x \in X$ and $\{f^{n_k}(x)\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a sequence in $X$ that converges to $x$. "Sequential Continuity is Equivalent to Continuity in Metric Space":
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sequential_Continuity_is_Equivalent_to_Continuity_in_Metric_Space

Comment: great, but why does this imply either $O(x)\subset\overline{O^+(x)}$ or$O(x)\subset\overline{O^-(x)}$ ?

Comment: Suppose $f^l(x) \in \mathcal{O}(x)$, then $f^l(x)$ is an adherent point of either $\mathcal{O}^+(x)$ ($n_k$ positive for infinitely many indices) or $\mathcal{O}^-(x)$ ($n_k$ negative for infinitely many indices).
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Adherent_Point

Comment: or rather suppose $u \in \mathcal{O}(x)$ which means there is $l \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f^l(x)=u$ (in case the last comment is not clear). Also notice since $|n_k| \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$, we either have $n_k+l>0$ [ $f^{n_k}(u) \in \mathcal{O}^+(x)$] or $n_k+l<0$  [ $f^{n_k}(u) \in \mathcal{O}^-(x)$] for infinitely many indices $k$.

Comment: great answer man , thank you for your patience !